# How to develop a general method for linq statements?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2013

I need to create a general routine in visual studio to get some parameters as input and return a list resulted from a repository. I am using Linq. But I am not sure how to develop this function and neither what key words I can use and find some resources.

This is a sample code that already is used in my program:

```
var lstReceiptDetails = Repository<TransactionDetail>()
    .Where(current => current.HeaderId == headerId)
    .OrderBy(current => current.DocumentRow)
    .ToList();
```

I need to change the above linq statement to something like the following pseudocode:

```
private List<> GetQuery(repositoryName,  conditionFieldName, orderFieldName )
{
var lstResult = Repository<repositiryName>()
    .Where(current => current.ConditionFieldName == conditionFieldName)
    .OrderBy(current => current.orderFieldName)
    .ToList();

Return(lstResult);
}
```

Any help is appreciate.
Maryam

Comment: Are we talking about Linq or Linq-to-SQL/EntityFramework?

Comment: what about using generic

Comment: If your list was a DataTable you could use .Field<string>("Column Name") which would make the code more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest way you can get is by using the following example below. I've tried a several ways to do this, but it would harm the usability and the readability. This is a compromise between code duplication and readability.

A sample POCO object:

```
class TransactionDetail
{
    public DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

The repositories:

```
abstract class GenericRepository<T>
{
    public List<T> GetQuery<TKey>(
        Func<T, bool> conditionFieldName, 
        Func<T, TKey> orderFieldName)
    {
        var lstResult = Repository()
            .Where(conditionFieldName)
            .OrderBy(orderFieldName)
            .ToList();

        return lstResult;
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> Repository()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class TransactionDetailRepository : GenericRepository<TransactionDetail>
{
}
```

And caller-side:

```
var repository = new TransactionDetailRepository();

var transactions = repository.GetQuery(
    x => x.AccountName == "Foo Bar",
    x => x.DateProcessed);
```

Argument checks should still be implemented properly though.

If this piece of code should be used in `EntityFramework` or Linq-to-SQL, parameters should be wrapped in `Expression<T>` such that, for example: `Func<T, bool>` becomes `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Comment: The generic parameter `T` is placed on `GenericRepository` so that there is no need to repeat it when someone calls the `GetQuery` method. The `TKey` can be inferred from the parameters, which makes calling the method easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the LINQ Dynamic Query Library that take string arguments instead of type-safe language operators.

Short example:

```
var result = Repository<repositoryName>().
  Where("Id = 1").
  Select("new(Id, Name)");
```

More information here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library